# Python Discord.py Bot Interval Message Send

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to create a bot for Discord using the discord.py library however when I am running the program it is not sending the message as expected. It is a simple bot that is suppose to send a message every 10 minutes to a channel. I am not getting any error messages in the command line and can't seem to see any obvious errors? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='my channel ID goes here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await message.channel.send("TEST")
        await asyncio.sleep(5) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('My token goes here')
```

Comment: Does it give any errors or does it just run. Also the `message.channel.send` should probably be `channel.send` since you're setting the channel manually and not from a message.

Comment: @duckboycool No errors, it just runs in the command line with the output below.

Logged in as
TestBot
Bot ID
------

Comment: And what does it do if you replace `await message.channel.send("TEST")`?

Comment: Just the same, just sits running in a command prompt.

Comment: Well the other thing I see is replacing `channel = discord.Object(id='id')` with `channel = client.get_channel(id)`. I'm not positive it's your issue, but that's the form I usually see it in.

Comment: Thanks, just tested with that but still getting the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: You need to fix a few typos. Use `client.is_closed()` instead of `client.is_closed`, `channel = client.get_channel(12345)` instead of `channel = discord.Object(id='12345')` and `await channel.send("TEST")` instead of `await message.channel.send("TEST")`.

Comment: Thanks @Benjin that has fixed it, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Although creating a task could work, I wouldn't recommend it when there are better options. Dpy's command.ext addon has a task based system built in directly, so let's look into using that instead.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

client = discord.Client()

@tasks.loop(minutes=10)
async def my_background_task():
    """A background task that gets invoked every 10 minutes."""
    channel = client.get_channel(754904403710050375) # Get the channel, the id has to be an int
    await channel.send('TEST!')
    
@my_background_task.before_loop
async def my_background_task_before_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

my_background_task.start()
client.run('Your token goes here')
```

The time until which the above loop will run is dependent upon human psychology, laws of energy and cosmos.
That is:

• You get bored of it

• The power goes down and your script stops working

• The universe explodes

Read more about it here:

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/

Answer (score 0):

If the channel ID is a string, [It should be an integer.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#snowflakes-are-int)

Turn this:

```
channel = discord.Object(id='my channel ID goes here')
```

into:

```
channel = discord.Object(id=101029321892839) # an example ID
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, try setting `'message.channel.send'` to `'channel.send'` and `client.is_closed` should be

```
client.is_closed() # put brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())`, just put the background function in the `on_ready` event. And take out `await client.wait_until_ready()` and just put the function in the `on_ready` event as well.
I have also changed the client variable, taken out unnecessary code, and added some modules.

```
import asyncio, discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".") # If you don't want a prefix just take out the parameter.

async def my_background_task():
    channel = discord.Object(id='my channel ID goes here')
    while True:
        await channel.send("TEST")
        await asyncio.sleep(5) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    my_background_task()

client.run('My token goes here')
```

Also in future when posting a question, please tag the python version as I don't know which version it is and then this and other answers could be wrong.